How to save a div into the DB without canvas size limitations?
I am trying to build a tool where it is possible to create your own personal poster. The users can modify their poster with different images, colors, text, ... All of it is contained in a single <div id="divToImage">. I would like to save this div into the database of the website as an image. Therefore I have already tried to use the html2canvas and dom-to-image library. These two libraries try to convert the div into a canvas which makes it possible to save or create a dataUrl of it.
However, the creation of the canvas has some limitations. The maximum amount of pixels on an iPhone is pretty low. It freezes my website when I try to convert the div into the canvas via one of those two dependencies.
So my question is whether there is another way to save the div into the DB without size limitations (because the image will be quite large in size and quality).
Maybe a way to change the increase the maximum size of the canvas on iPhone? ...
I am a bit stuck here on the possibilities
EDIT:
Currently I am using the following simplified code:
html2canvas(document.getElementById("divToImage"), { 
        scale: 5,
        allowTaint: true,
        imageTimeout: 15000,
        logging: true,
        useCORS: true,
    }).then(function (canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
            saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
        });
    }

As you can see I am currently using the html2canvas to create a canvas of the div. Afterwards, I am using the saveAs from FileSaver for saving the image locally (testing) or I try to apply the toDataUrl() function to save this url in the DB. Like below:
 var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

Both the options work on desktop or Android phones, but not on iPhones. Which could be caused by the limitations of size of a canvas on ios. The code freezes on the then(function (canvas) ...) call in that case.
I am open for every solution which makes it possible to save the div on every possible desktop and phone. Whether it is Javascript based or PHP based.

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

@NicoHaase I have added some extra code/explanation on the question. I am open for every solution, I do not know whats possible to fix the problem. Maybe the reason that its not working on iPhone is not because of the limitation of the canvas size.. I am not sure. Any help or pointers would be great

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq on the maximum image sizes on iOS: "The maximum size for a canvas element is 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM" - and there probably isn't anything you can do about that in itself. Not sure how exactly the library works, maybe(!) you could try and work around this, by using the width/height parameters and x/y offsets, to get your "big" element rendered into multiple partial images (which you could then combine again on the server side.)

@CBroe are you sure this is a current problem? Even the iPhone 3GS from 2009 was equipped with 256 MB RAM

@NicoHaase no, not sure - OP should perhaps verify if the issue doesn't occur for smaller sizes. But https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#maximum_canvas_size also says, "notably iOS devices limit the canvas size to only 4,096 x 4,096 pixels", and https://caniuse.com/canvas mentions the same 3 / 5 mega pixel limits, as the html2canvas FAQ - but no mention, on how old that info is.

caniuse also mentions, "JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level entry point." - could perhaps also be, that it actually runs into that limitation somewhere, I suppose.

@CBroe I have tried to save an image with a height and width of just 100 on Iphone, but even that does not work. When looking at the console, I can see the following logs from html2canvas: Canvas renderer initialized (100x100) with scale 1 and Finished rendering. So I assume it was possible to create the canvas, but applying the canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  or the canvas.toBlob() blocks the device. No logs were shown by or after one of these methods... This has nothing to do with the html2canvas limits I guess? ...

No, doesn't sound like it has anything to do with size limits then. Does the demo ("Try it out" button) on https://html2canvas.hertzen.com work?

The demo does seem to work
